# do we need to synchronise the DB calls if multithreading is involved?

Tags: multithreading, postgresql

I have a scenario where two threads invoke a method and this method generated a sequence using postgres nextval(test_sequence).
test_sequence is initailly assigned to 1.

```
public String createNotification() {
        logger.info("createNotification ENTRY");
        Future<String> futRes = this.threadPool.submit(new Callable<String>() {

            @Override
            public String call() {
                    String notificationID = getNotificationId();//DB CALL TO GENERATE THE NEXT SEQUENCE.

                    boolean isInsertSuccess = notificationDaoService.insertNotificationIntoDB(notificationID);
                    if (isInsertSuccess == true) {
                        return notificationID;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }

            }
        });

        try {
            return futRes.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Issue while getting value from future with exception :", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So in the above snippet, getNotificationId() will generate the sequence and insertNotificationIntoDB() wil insert the generated notification id to the table.

I some times observing the primary key voilation exception when multiple threads try to invoke createNotification().

So i am thinking to synchronise the db calls as mentioned below,

```
synchronised(object)
{
String notificationID = getNotificationId();

                    boolean isInsertSuccess = notificationDaoService.insertNotificationIntoDB(notificationID);
}
```

is this solution ok?
and also i want to ask if i can generalise that if multiple threads are accessing a function and if that function has DB calls that does basic CRUD, then all the DB calls needs to be synchronised. Is this right inference?

Comment: Postgres should handle this kind of concurrency just fine without any synchronisation, as long as each thread is using a different connection. It's hard to guess where the race condition is without seeing what's inside `getNotificationId()` `insertNotificationIntoDB()`.

Comment: No, it's not necessary to synchronize calls to `nextval()`. Sequences are optimized for high concurrent throughput

Comment: I see. but i came across a scenario where same notificationid was returned to both the threads and when the same notification ids were tried to insert into the data base, i got primary key voilation exception since notification id is the primary key for the table.